# Updating array, trouble with index

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a trouble with my code, using mongodb c# driver.
This trouble looks like the one described here : http://www.ciiycode.com/0iiBNWWexjex/how-to-update-items-in-an-arraylist-with-mongo-c-driver.html
which seems to have been solved.

I want to update a bi-dimensionnal array in my document.
If I use

```
myarray[0,3]
```

it works, however if I use variable like

```
int a = 0;
int b = 3;
myarray[a,b]
```

it gives me a "Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression ..." error

Full code :

```
int a = 0;
int b = 3;    
var update = Builders<sensorValuesDocument>.Update                  
                    .Set(e => e.values[a][b]
                    , new sensorValues()
                    {
                        v = 0,
                        t = 0,
                        h = 0,
                        c = 0,
                        l = 0
                    }) ...
```

and my document class :

```
public class sensorValuesDocument
    {
        ...
        public List<List<sensorValues>> values { get; set; }
        ...
    }

 public class sensorValues
    {
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Double, AllowTruncation = true)]
        public float? t { get; set; }
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Double, AllowTruncation = true)]
        public float? v { get; set; }
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Double, AllowTruncation = true)]
        public float? h { get; set; }
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Double, AllowTruncation = true)]
        public float? l { get; set; }
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Double, AllowTruncation = true)]
        public float? c { get; set; }
    }
```

If I replace the previous code with .Set(e => e.values[0][3]
It works just fine.
Any idea/workaround please ?
Thanks in advance

Julien

Comment: It should be a Mongo driver issue with expression trees, where it can't extract array indexes from variables and it requires literals..

Comment: Maybe should I file a bug on their website ?

Comment: Maybe, maybe. BTW docs says that this update method is obsolete. Am I wrong?

Comment: mmmmh no, I don't think so, and this is the method showcased in the official documentation. Anyway we'll see I am going to submit a bug resolution request

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's some issue with MongoDB C# driver where it can't translate the whole `.Set(...)` expression tree when array access' indexes are *variables*.

Fortunately, C# is a very very powerful language and it supports *expression trees* which let you programatically-create expressions like a data structure.

At the end of the day, you need an expression like this: `listOfLists => listOfLists [0][3]` using integer literals, right?

See the following code:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 3;

// This is the input parameter for the expression (i.e. the (doc) => part of the expression)
ParameterExpression valuesDocumentParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(sensorValuesDocument));
// This is the "values" property access. Now we would have the following expression:
// (doc) => doc.values
MemberExpression listOfListPropertyAccess = Expression.Property(valuesDocumentParameter, "values");

// This is accessing the parent list: (doc) => doc.values[0]
IndexExpression parentListIndexerAccess = Expression.Property
(
    listOfListPropertyAccess, 
    "Item", 
    new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(a) }
);

// This is accessing the nested list: (doc) => doc.values[0][3]
IndexExpression nestedListIndexerAccess = Expression.Property
(
    parentListIndexerAccess, 
    "Item", 
    new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(b) }
);

// This builds the full expression tree!
Expression<Func<sensorValuesDocument, sensorValues>> setExpr =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<sensorValuesDocument, sensorValues>>
    (
        nestedListIndexerAccess,
        valuesDocumentParameter
    );
```

Now you can give `setExpr` to `Update.Set(...)`: `Update.Set(setExpr)`.

I believe that this should do the trick and workaround the MongoDB driver's issue, since you're giving what it really expects: an array access using literals instead of variables.

Comment: Thanks Matias. This is kind of powerful, and complicated as well. I tried your solution and I get a type mismatch. Maybe is it because the sensorValues is not directly the object I am querying, but instead I should query e.values (which is the nested list if you look at the sensorValueDocument definition) ? Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Models.sensorValues[*,*], Models.sensorValues>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Controllers.sensorValuesDocument, Models.sensorValues>>'

Comment: @JulienS Ah, yeah... I see... it requires few modifications to build up the right expression tree... If you can wait until tomorrow I'll fix it. I'll try to get it fixed before if I can

Comment: Thanks Matias for your help. I would be glad to have your elegant solution :-) In the meantime, I found a (really less beautiful) workaround by constructing the string to target the values array item : .Set("values." + a + "." + b, new sensorValues() ...

Comment: @JulienS Finally I did it! :) Try my updated code. I've removed the re-use part from the previous answer's versión because I believe that a generalization here wouldn't matter at all... Let me know if it worked!

Comment: I tried your code, however I get the same type of error : ExceptionMessage=Unable to determine the serialization information for Param_0 => Param_0.values.Item[17].Item[2] . Apparently, the problem has just be postponed to another variable :-/ Anyway thanks for your help, I stick with my "ugly" solution for now ;-)

Comment: @JulienS Can you try this? try to give `Expression<Func<sensorValuesDocument, sensorValues>> expr = doc => doc.values[0][3];`  as argument. I mean, give `expr`. I checked that the resulting expression is different than the one I gave you in my updated answer using watch expressions. Mine does the `Ítem` thing, and the other one does `get_Item(0).get_Item(3)` (for example)